# How to paint a docked JToolBar over the rest of the components from the panel

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

Is there any way to paint a docked JToolBar OVER the rest of the components from an existing panel?

Basically I want, when docking the toolbar (from a floating position), not to interfere with my other components and existing layout.

simple example, just to get started..

```
public class ToolBarSample {

 public static void main(final String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JToolBar Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();

    toolbar.add(new JButton("button"));
    toolbar.add(new JButton("button 2"));

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(new JLabel("I want this to be under the toolbar"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // set the toolbar floating
    ((BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI()).setFloatingLocation(10, 10);
    ((BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI()).setFloating(true, null);

    // TODO - after application starts, manually dock the toolbar to any position (north/east...)

    frame.setSize(250, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add the toolbar directly to the [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) of the `JFrame` .

Here is some useful documentation : [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JToolBar Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();

    toolbar.add(new JButton("button"));
    toolbar.add(new JButton("button 2"));

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    //contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(new JLabel("I want this to be under the toolbar"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = frame.getLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    layeredPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // set the toolbar floating
    ((BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI()).setFloatingLocation(10, 10);
    ((BasicToolBarUI) toolbar.getUI()).setFloating(true, null);

    // TODO - after application starts, manually dock the toolbar to any position (north/east...)

    frame.setSize(250, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```